# How to add a new hidden input fields to the form on submit

Tags: javascript

I want to pass certain hidden parameters in a request when some conditions are met.

For example I want to pass these if this condition is true:

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
 function checkClosureLevel()
 {
    var openLevel = document.getElementById('openLevel');
    var phyCompLevel = document.getElementById('phyCompLevel');
    var finCompLevel = document.getElementById('finCompLevel');

    if (openLevel.checked) { 
      //PASS HIDDEN FORM VARIABLES HERE AND SUBMIT FORM 
    }
 }
</script>

<form action="process.det_details" method="post" name="detParameterForm">
  <fieldset class="det">
    <legend>Closure Level</legend>
    <input type="checkbox" name="openLevel" >Open</input><br/>
    <input type="checkbox" name="phyCompLevel" >Physically Complete</input>
    <br/>
    <input type="checkbox" name="finCompLevel" >Financially Complete</input>
  </fieldset>
</form>
```

Comment: Append a hidden input element, with a given `name` and `value`.

Comment: Can you show the actual code? Your current code looks very broken, with the `<input>` elements being placed at the top, then JavaScript code between, without `<script>` tags, and finally the starting `<form>` tag, without any more code.

Comment: no, no ..those hidden variables are right next to the input "checkboxes" at the bottom of the page.  Im just showing what I would need passed over to the request.

Comment: The structure **matters**. Can you show the real structure, instead of randomly ordered bits of your code?

Comment: The script is going to be a series of "if" checks and on each if Im going to pass 3 specific hidden variables and submit the form.  I just want to know how to construct in javascript how to set a hidden those 2 variable and subit the form....

Comment: Agree with Rob - The inputs doubtless should be between form tags, and the javascript is floating around without being enclosed in     <javascript> tags. The name tag for the inputs looks a little unusual to me (unless you're doing something clever which I've never seen..)

Comment: Yes Im passing the names and values to a map in a form bean and doing some magic there:)....But dont concern yourself with that...I just need to know how to pass for example `<input type="hidden" name="filterCriteria('SOURCE_OF_REPAIR').fieldName" value="SOURCE_OF_REPAIR"/> <input type="hidden" name="filterCriteria('SOURCE_OF_REPAIR').operation" value="in"/>` in javascript and submit the form

Answer (score 52, accepted):

The [`document.forms`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/document.forms) object is a collection of all `<form>` elements in the page. It has numeric indexes, and named items. The named items correspond to a `name` attribute of each `<form>`.

```
var theForm = document.forms['detParameterForm'];
```

To make appending data easier, you can create a function which adds data for a given form.

```
function addHidden(theForm, key, value) {
    // Create a hidden input element, and append it to the form:
    var input = document.createElement('input');
    input.type = 'hidden';
    input.name = key; // 'the key/name of the attribute/field that is sent to the server
    input.value = value;
    theForm.appendChild(input);
}

// Form reference:
var theForm = document.forms['detParameterForm'];

// Add data:
addHidden(theForm, 'key-one', 'value');
addHidden(theForm, 'another', 'meow');
addHidden(theForm, 'foobarz', 'baws');

// Submit the form:
theForm.submit();
```

Comment: @JackScott Thanks for [your edit](http://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/2484387).

Comment: How can you do the same for Ajax forms?

Comment: @HaBo That is very specific to the web application that generates the form.

Comment: I am  on ASP.NET MVC 5 Razors I have a Ajax form for which I am doing some validation with OnBegin Property of the Ajax Form, in that JS function I am appending the input elements. in my case my elements are getting appended after the post hits the server. Trying to find some help on how to append those elements before the post hits the server

Comment: @HaBo Doesn't ring a bell here. I suggest to create a new question and add all relevant details plus tags.

Comment: Could you explain the `'name-as-seen-at-the-server'` in your example?

Comment: @boolean.is.null It is a comment. If you delete `key;`, then you would see `'name-as....'` at the server. Currently it does not have any effect on the execution of the code.