# How do I dynamically add html elements to a page and access them in asp.net?

Tags: javascript, c#, html, asp.net, visual-studio

Good day,

I have been trying for over a day now to figure out a way to dynamically add elements to a web page using visual studio and access their values. I am either over-complicating the whole thing, I'm being dumb, or there is genuinely no way in which to do what I'm trying to do haha. 
I am trying to create a page that should be able to generate possibly over 100 of the following html item sets:
It is basically a question and answer form for creating a multiple choice test. There is an area to type a question and then additional text boxes just to add in the multiple choice. There is also a button that can add an extra 2 textboxes to the answer area (whether they are created and added to a div in the table row or hidden and then revealed when the button is pressed.)

---

[Textbox for question]

[Textbox][Textbox][Textbox][Textbox] [Button that adds additional textbox to this row (only an extra 2 at maximum)]

[Confirm button to submit the text in the textboxes]

---

[Button that adds another copy of the elements above (up to 100)]

I would love to create just a normal form (as that's probably easiest), but this needs to work on the web. I know keeping track of all of this content can be a nightmare, but I can't think of an alternative (well, I have thought of an alternative but it seems to be more complicated). I have tried the following:
I tried adding a div into a table cell to add the textboxes, but I couldn't access the div afterwards. Is there a way to do this? If I could access the elements I create using the innerHtml method, I would be more or less fine, but I cannot find anything online.

```
QuestionContent.InnerHtml += "<table runat=\"server\" style=\"width: 100 %; \"><tr><td> Question " + _QuestionNum + " </td></tr><tr><td class=\"auto - style1\"><div id=\"divQ"+_QuestioNum+"\"></div></td></tr></table>"; 
//Might have an issue adding an element with runat=server, but this was the only way I could think of extracting a value that is created dynamically in C#.
                    ((System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlGenericControl)mainPanel.FindControl("divQ1")).InnerHtml = "<asp:TextBox ID=\"txtChoice1\" runat=\"server\">Choice1</asp:TextBox>"; 
    //Here I try to access the div created above. Unrelated: Also tried with a normal textbox, but I realise that creating an asp textbox here might cause issues.
```

I just cannot seem to access anything I create in C#. Is there a better way? Upon giving up on this idea, I tried creating elements using javascript. I still need to find out if I can pass values through to C# using javascript, but I am stuck with another issue now. Whenever the below code runs, the elements appear but then immediately disappear. Is this an issue with asp.net? The google results weren't very helpful.

```
function addQuestion() {
if (numQuestions == limit) {
    alert('Maximum question limit reached. Consider breaking this test up into multiple tests.');
}
else {
    var newdiv = document.createElement('div');
    newdiv.setAttribute('id', 'divQ' + numQuestions);
    newdiv.innerHTML = '<table><tr><td> Question' + numQuestions + '</td></tr><tr><td>';
    for(var i=0;i<6;i++){
        newdiv.innerHTML += "<input type=\"text\" name=\"textBox"+i+"\">";
    }
    newdiv.innerHTML += '</td></tr></table>';
    numQuestions++;
    document.getElementById('divQuestionContent').appendChild(newdiv);       
}
```

}

However, I would like to avoid using javascript if I can. Is there a better way to create this page? Have I simply done something wrong? Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: With out JavaScript no dynamic content for you

Comment: I think it would be better if you picked up some books on web development.

Comment: I definitely need to pick up some books on web dev haha.

Answer (score 1):

I think you are mixin server and client side code.

**1st)** Create html form with your first known necesary fields

**2nd)** Javascript part. User add fields to the form (need to be done in Javascript, client side ), check this answer:
[How add new hidden input fields to the form on submit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9251301/how-add-new-hidden-input-fields-to-the-form-on-submit)

**3rd)** C# part . On form request, you need to loop over all request.form items, as you can't know how many they are. This can be done with something like this:

```
StringBuilder s = new StringBuilder();
foreach (string key in Request.Form.Keys)
{
    s.AppendLine(key + ": " + Request.Form[key]);
}
string formData = s.ToString();
```

Comment: Thanks! I'll check it out.