# JavaScript function to add an input field to an HTML form unclear

Tags: javascript, html, forms

I've come across [this nifty little function](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9251540/6921751), to add a hidden input field to an HTML form with JavaScript.

Here's the code:

```
function addHidden(theForm, key, value) {
    // Create a hidden input element, and append it to the form:
    var input = document.createElement('input');
    input.type = 'hidden';
    input.name = key;'name-as-seen-at-the-server';
    input.value = value;
    theForm.appendChild(input);
}

// Form reference:
var theForm = document.forms['detParameterForm'];

// Add data:
addHidden(theForm, 'key-one', 'value');
addHidden(theForm, 'another', 'meow');
addHidden(theForm, 'foobarz', 'baws');

// Submit the form:
theForm.submit();
```

What I do not understand is the `'name-as-seen-at-the-server'` in `input.name = key;'name-as-seen-at-the-server';`.

What exactly does this set and how is it used?

Comment: In context given (a function that appends inputs to DOM), it is nothing. The key can be any arbitrarily determined string.

Comment: I ran it on jsfiddle and `'name-as-seen-at-the-server';`  does nothing. Then value os `key` is just assigned to the variable on the left.

Comment: Comment out name-as-seen-at-the-server or delete it, it's just your field name. nothing else

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's likely just describing the `key` input. Comment it out or remove it, and all should work just fine.
Change the line `input.name = key;'name-as-seen-at-the-server';` to `input.name = key;//'name-as-seen-at-the-server';`

Comment: So this will really just create the input field with the name `key` and the value `value`, right? thank you! I just tried it with jsbin, it works just fine - thanks!