# How to add values to a form via javascript?

Tags: javascript, php, html

So what im trying is to add POST inputs to a form on an `Onclick function`. so, when i check the info is OK via `Javascript`, before doing via Javascript `form.submit()` I want to add more information, for example an IdCrono.
What im doing right now is in `Form.action = "myPhpFunction.php"` is add GET variables via the action so it would be

```
"myPhpFunction.php?key=1&IdCrono=1"
```

anyway to add Key and IdCrono to the POST via javaScript?

My code looks like this:

```js
function GuardarMilestone(a) {
  var id = a.id;
  var idCrono = Math.floor(a.id / 10);
  alert(idCrono);
  var form = document.getElementById("Form" + id);
  if (id % 10 == 0) {
    //alert("Resto 0");
    var date = form.elements["FechaInicio"];
  } else {
    //alert("Resto 5");
    var date = form.elements["FechaFin"];
  }
  if (date.value != "") {
    form.action = "InteriorInternalFunciones.php?key=1&id=" + id;
    form.target = "_self";
    form.submit();
  } else {
    alert("Please fill in the date before saving");
  }
}
```

```html
<form method="POST" id="Form<?php echo $rstMilestones->fields['IdCronograma']; ?>0" action="">
  <input type="date" style="font-size: 9px; font-style: bold;" name="FechaInicio" value="<?php echo $strFaseInicioSinFormato;?>">
  <input type="hidden" name="IdCronograma" value="<?php echo $rstMilestones->fields['IdCronograma']; ?>">
  <a href="#botones" id="<?php echo $rstMilestones->fields['IdCronograma']; ?>0" onclick="GuardarMilestone(this)"><img src="images/PC_si.png" alt="Save"></a>
  <a href="#botones" id="<?php echo $rstMilestones->fields['IdCronograma']; ?>0" onclick="EditarFechaCronograma(this)"><img src="images/PC_no.png" alt="cancel"></a>
</form>
```

Comment: Add two hidden inputs for `key, id` with a empty value and give them an id (html attribute). Then on submit you can update the hidden inputs before submit the form for real.  `document.getElementById("IdCrono").value = id;`

Comment: Your form has 'POST' and you are creating 'GET' is that intentional?

Comment: @RST yes its intentional, because i don't know if i can dynamically add POST variables to send, I don't like useing GET variables. That's why I'm asking if there is a way to do it.

Comment: @JustOnUnderMillions Thanks i actually never thought about that haha, so simple, but efective. But is there still a way to do it with out the input hiddens? if not I'll just use that

Comment: @JustOnUnderMillions already provided the scenario for adding POST variables before send

Comment: @Juanfri Lira Thing it is also possible to at the data dircty to the `form` variable. Check for an link and drop it later here.

Comment: @JuanfriLira Read more here http://stackoverflow.com/a/9251540/4916265

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Maybe this will help, just add this function to your code:

```
function addFields(form, inputName, inputValue) {
    // Create an <input> element
    var input = document.createElement("input");
    input.type = "hidden";
    input.name = inputName;
    input.value = inputValue;
    form.appendChild(input);
}
```

and replace this line:

```
form.action = "InteriorInternalFunciones.php?key=1&id=" + id;
```

with this:

```
form.action = "InteriorInternalFunciones.php;
addFields(form, "key", 1);
addFields(form, "id", id);
```

This will add hidden fields to your code just before form is submitted, and all will be send with POST method.