# How to extract the specific AdWord keyword that a client clicked on?

Tags: google-analytics, google-ads-api

I'm using AdWords to help generate form submissions, and a form submission is my heuristic for a conversion.

I want to fetch the specific AdWords keyword that generated a conversion and submit it along with the form so that I can track which keyword are generating which submissions. Is this possible?

I don't see an cookie that relates to a Google Ad click, and the automatically appended gclid only contains a timestamp when decoded.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's not programming related

Comment: Just because you don't know the answer doesn't mean it's not programming related.

Comment: Please edit the question and include some code that you are having an issue with and we will happly help you

Comment: I don't know the answer to the question, that's why I'm asking it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using autotagging in Adwords then you will not get the keyword in realtime to send it along with the form.

You would either need to use manual tagging, and extract the value from the utm_term parameter, or [configure valuetrack parameters to have the keyword/matchtype in your destinantion url](https://support.google.com/adwords/answer/6305529?hl=en&ref_topic=6031980).

In both cases you'd need to store the value from the query parameter ([e.g. in a cookie](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4825683/how-do-i-create-and-read-a-value-from-cookie)), read it in the page with the form and append a [hidden form field to your form](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9251301/how-to-add-a-new-hidden-input-fields-to-the-form-on-submit) that is set to the proper value.

Comment: This is exactly what I needed. I also found this tutorial for manual tagging which was very helpful: https://docs.heapanalytics.com/docs/manual-and-autotagging-for-adwords